# Expanding menu shifts to the right after slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a mobile menu and for some reason whenever you expand the menu, the list items shift the right a bit and the `border-bottom` does not cover the entire width of the expanded menu.

To see the mobile part of the menu, shrink the screen down some. Once you click the menu icon, you will see that the list doesn't just go straight down, it looks to move to the right. Then the border issue is very easy to see.

See snippet to view the issue.

```js
$('span.nav-btn').click(function () {
  $('ul.nav_list').slideToggle(500);
 })
 $(window).resize(function (){
  if ( $(window).width() > 600 ) {
   $('ul.nav_list').removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 
 }
 .header {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 80px;
 }
 .header_wrap {
  margin: 0 15%;
 }
 .logo {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
 }
 .nav_list {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
 }
 .nav_list > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 15px;
 }
 .nav_list > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #FFF;
 }
 
 @media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  body {
   background-color: blue;
  }
  .header_wrap {
   margin: 0 5%;
  }
  .nav_list {
   text-align: center;
   display: none;
   margin-top: 60px;
  }
  .nav_list > li {
   display: block;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  }
  .nav-btn {
   display: block;
   background-color: #333;
   color: #FFF;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   text-align: right;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .nav-btn:before {
   background-image: url('http://realtorcatch.com/icons/mobile_menu_bttn.png');
   background-size: 28px 28px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 28px;
   height: 28px;
   content:"";
   display: block;
   float: right;
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <header class="header">
  <div class="header_wrap">
   <div class="logo">Garbrandt Construction</div>
   <nav>
    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <ul class="nav_list">
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the last line to your nav_list (padding-left:0 is needed):

```
.nav_list {
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 60px;
  padding-left:0;
    }
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe6kxrd9/)

Comment: Thanks, I added that after the other answer was given and it helped with the `bottom-border`. Do you have any idea with the mobile menu's list is shifting to the right slightly? Also do you know how I can get the entire menu section to be clickable to the list page instead of just the text?

Comment: Hello there, try this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xe6kxrd9/1/ Note that I swapped the <a> and <li> tags and added width:auto and width:100% to them. Also all <a> tags received a no-text-decoration css property at the beginning. I believe it is not shifting to the right now and the whole section is clickable.

Comment: Is there another way to make the entire bar clickable instead of switching the list inside of the link?

Comment: Well, not perfectly but there is a way to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/xe6kxrd9/2/ Note how the paddings on the <li> and the display+width on the <a> are set. Although I can see no reason to go with this solution, since the height is not perfect this way and sizing <a> is a bit unusual in my opinion (not to mention it's easier to make the whole <li> an anchor)

Comment: Cool. I just went with your first approach and it works perfectly. I made a couple of changes, but you definitely pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should add a padding of 0 to the ul element. Padding: 0 or padding-left: 0 should do it.

```
.nav_list {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Lists automatically have padding to the left;

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the border, but do you have any issue with why the list items move to the right slightly?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that part. Try adding a width: 100% to the .nav_list when in a mobile query.